# Pylons - Redirects will drop from HTTPS to HTTP unless I specify the protocol... Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: python, ssl, redirect, https, pylons

On my Pylons website, I have my login form sending it's data to 'https://mysite.com'. Upon a successful login, a redirect takes place to send them to their profile page.

```
redirect(url(controller='profile'))
```

This sends the user to `http://mysite.com/profile` instead of `https://mysite.com/profile`. The only way I've found to fix this is to change the redirect to:

```
redirect(url(controller='profile', protocol='https'))
```

The problem I have with this is "what if, for whatever reason, my cert goes away and I have to drop SSL" I don't want to have to go through my entire code looking for all redirects I specify the 'https' protocol in. I want my login to send the user to HTTPS and that's it...

Is there a reason the redirect drops to HTTP? Is there a way to stop it? :/

Answer (score 4):

Since I spent a couple of hours wading through the pylons/routes/beaker/etc. source I thought I'd share my solution.

First a bit of context. I'm using an elastic load balancer (ELB) on AWS with SSL termination. The application is built to run solely over https; this is a post-firesheep world after all. It's layered like so:

```
ELB -> nginx -> pasteWSGI -> pylons
```

ELB is jolly good in terms of simplicity but any call to pylons.controllers.util.redirect would trigger a 302 Redirect to "http://mysite/". The ELB would not change that on the way back (no reason to) and so my browser would be sent back to port 80 and there is no ELB listening on that port.

I've tried updating the Mapper as suggested above.

1. it did not work,
2. I wanted my redirects to be relative. Switching to https in pylons means that the URL generator goes and fetches the host to create a new URL (https://localhost/....)

Note that Mapper.redirect_to works out of the box and uses relative redirects so there is no need to mess with that. The fundamental problem is that controllers.redirect uses a slightly different code path. In particular, in Routes, the controllers.util.redirect is not a redirect (there's an "if routes and routes.redirect" which evals to False).

My solution: replace all calls to redirect by a new controller method (called redirect too) to change redirects from absolute to relative redirects.

The code is as follows:

lib/helpers.py

```
def relative_redirect(to_url, start_response):
    """Returns a redirect that is compatible with AWS ELB (no absolute http responses)
    Using pylons.controllers.util.redirect triggers an exception that'll be turned into a 302
    But with an absolute path so the response does not contains https but simple http
    """
    start_response("302 Found", [("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8"), ("Location", url(to_url))])
    return ["You are being redirected to {0}".format(url(to_url))]
```

With that bit called from the base class of my controllers:

```
class BaseController(WSGIController):
   ...
   def redirect(self, to_url):
        """Force a relative redirection, to work with AWS ELB"""
        return relative_redirect(to_url, self.start_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd customize the Mapper so that every call to "url" would force the correct protocol...
Inside `routing.py`:

```
class CustomMapper(Mapper):

    def generate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["protocol"] = "https"
        return Mapper.generate(self, *args, **kwargs)

def make_map(config):
    """Create, configure and return the routes Mapper"""
    map = CustomMapper(directory=config['pylons.paths']['controllers'],
                       always_scan=config['debug'])
```